An optimization problem and proof of necessity
The problem is formulated as follows
$
\max  f\left( x_k,y_k \right) =\log _2\left( 1+Ax_1y_{1}^{2} \right) +\log _2\left( 1+Ax_2y_{2}^{2} \right) -\log_2 \left( 1+ACD^2 \right) 
\\
s.t\,\,x_1+x_2=C,
\\
\,\,   y_1+y_2=D,
\\
\,\,   x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2\geqslant 0,
$
where $A$ is a positive constant and $C,D>0$. I want to know what relationship should exist between $C$ and $D$ there exists at least one pair of $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$ such that $f\left( x_k,y_k \right)>0$. And I hope to obtain the optimal value of $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$  when $f\left( x_k,y_k \right)>0$.
For special case, when $x_{1}^{*}=x_{2}^{*}=\dfrac{C}{2},y_{1}^{*}=y_{2}^{*}=\dfrac{D}{2}$ and $f\left( x_k,y_k \right)>0$,we have $f\left( x_{1}^{*},x_{2}^{*},y_{1}^{*},y_{2}^{*} \right) >0\rightarrow \left( 1+\frac{ACD^2}{8} \right) ^2-\left( 1+ACD^2 \right) >0\rightarrow \frac{\left( ACD^2 \right) ^2}{64}>\frac{3ACD^2}{4}
\\ \rightarrow ACD^2>48$, which means that the optimal solution for $x_k$ and $y_k$ are $\frac{C}{2}$ and $\frac{D}{2}$ when $f\left( x_k,y_k \right)>0$.
Besides, through MATLAB I found that when  $ACD^2<48$, $f\left( x_k,y_k \right) \leqslant 0$. In other words, there does not exist any set of $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$ that makes $f\left( x_k,y_k \right)>0$ when  $ACD^2<48$.
Therefore, the original problem is equivalent to proving that $ACD^2>48$ is a necessary and sufficient condition for existing at least one pair of $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$ such that $f\left( x_k,y_k \right)>0$. By using specific examples, we can derive the sufficient condition. Therefore, I hope to prove the necessity and that the optimal solution for $x_k$ and $y_k$ are $\frac{C}{2}$ and $\frac{D}{2}$ when $f\left( x_k,y_k \right)>0$.
I have attempted multiple times with derivative analysis and proof by contradiction, but it seems to be ineffective. I hope to receive some guidance on the proof.

Is the problem one of maximization or minimization? You didn't specify this in your question.

@EliasCosta I have edited it and I hope to obtain the values of x and y when the objective function is greater than 0.

The big question that intrigues me is how you obtained this number 48. Could you add to your question how you got that number?

@EliasCosta I added the solution procedure and it is just the special case. This special value x and y is intuitive but somewhat difficult to account for.

You say you "hope to find" the optimal solution; does that mean you do not have an analytical solution for $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2$ in terms of $A,C$ and $D$?

Remark. If $ACD^2 > 48$, we have $g(C, D) = (1 + A\cdot C/2\cdot (D/2)^2)(1 + A\cdot C/2 \cdot (D/2)^2)$, i.e. $x_1^\ast = x_2^\ast = C/2, y_1^\ast = y_2^\ast = D/2$. The proof is similar.
Problem. Let $A > 0$ be given. For $C, D > 0$, let
$$g(C, D) := \max_{(x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2)\in \Omega}
(1 + Ax_1y_1^2)(1 + Ax_2y_2^2)$$
where $\Omega = \{(x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2)\, : \, x_1 + x_2 = C;\,  y_1 + y_2 = D;\, x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2 \ge 0 \}$.
Prove that $g(C, D) > 1 + ACD^2$ if and only if
$ACD^2 > 48$.
$\phantom{2}$
Proof.
(1) Let us prove that if $ACD^2 \le 48$, then $g(C, D) \le 1 + ACD^2$.
If $x_1x_2y_1y_2 = 0$, then $(1 + Ax_1y_1^2)(1 + Ax_2y_2^2) \le 1 + ACD^2$.
If $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2 > 0$, we have
\begin{align*}
 &1 + ACD^2 - (1 + Ax_1y_1^2)(1 + Ax_2y_2^2) \\
 ={}& \frac{ACD^2}{(1+s)^2(1+r)^4} \cdot h(r, s)\\
 \ge{}& \frac{ACD^2}{(1+s)^2(1+r)^4} \cdot h_1(r, s)\\
 \ge{}& 0
\end{align*}
where $s := \frac{x_2}{x_1}, r := \frac{y_2}{y_1}$, and
\begin{align*}
 h(r, s) &:= -ACD^2 \cdot{r}^{2}s+{r}^{4}s+2\,{r}^{3}{s}^{2}+{r}^{4}+6\,{r}^{3}s+5\,{
  r}^{2}{s}^{2}\\
 &\qquad +4\,{r}^{3}+10\,{r}^{2}s+4\,r{s}^{2}+5\,{r}^{2}+6\,rs+{s}
 ^{2}+2\,r+s,\\
 h_1(r, s) &:= -48 \cdot{r}^{2}s+{r}^{4}s+2\,{r}^{3}{s}^{2}+{r}^{4}+6\,{r}^{3}s+5\,{
  r}^{2}{s}^{2}\\
 &\qquad +4\,{r}^{3}+10\,{r}^{2}s+4\,r{s}^{2}+5\,{r}^{2}+6\,rs+{s}
 ^{2}+2\,r+s.
\end{align*}
(2) Let us prove that if $ACD^2 > 48$, then $g(C, D) > 1 + ACD^2$.
We have
$$g(C, D) \ge (1 + A\cdot C/2\cdot (D/2)^2)(1 + A\cdot C/2 \cdot (D/2)^2)
> 1 + ACD^2.$$
We are done.

Thank you very much. But I want to know how you get$1+ACD^2-(1+Ax_1y_{1}^{2})(1+Ax_2y_{2}^{2})\rightarrow \frac{ACD^2}{(1+s)^2(1+r)^4}\cdot h(r,s)
$.Is any trick employed in between?

@ChenEric Yes, from $x_1 + x_2 = C$, we use the parameterization $x_1 = \frac{C}{1 + s}, x_2 = \frac{sC}{1+s}$. Then simplify the expression to get that.

sorry. I have one last question: How was $h_1(r,s)\geqslant 0
$ obtained? It doesn't seem obvious from the derivative analysis I conducted. Was it verified using software?@River Li

@ChenEric Feel free to ask any questions. Yes, it is not obvious that $h_1(r, s) \ge 0$ for all $r, s \ge 0$. We can verify it by e.g. Mathematica (a computer algebra system). I think there should be a human verifiable solution since it is quadratic in $s$.

Thank you very much！

@ChenEric You are welcome.

EDIT. This answer explores the necessary and sufficient conditions for $f(x_k,y_k)>0$ without restricting the values of $x_1$, $x_2$, $y_1$ and $y_2$. This is necessary because restricting $y_k$ and $x_k$ to functions of $C$ and $D$ with the restrictions $x_1+x_2=C$ and $y_1+y_2=D$ can lead to contradictions.
The objective function to be maximized is
$$
f(x_k,y_k)=\log_{2}\Big( ( 1+Ax_1y_{1}^{2})( 1+Ax_2y_{2}^{2})( 1+ACD^2)^{-1}\Big)
$$
It is easy to conclude  that
$$ 
f(x_{k},y_{k})>0 \quad \mbox{for all} \; x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2\geq 0 \mbox{ and } A>0 \tag{1}
$$
if, and only if,
$$
( 1+Ax_1y_{1}^{2})( 1+Ax_2y_{2}^{2})( 1+ACD^2)^{-1}>1 \; \mbox{for all}\quad  x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2\geq 0 \mbox{ and } A>0 \tag{2}
$$
After some algebraic manipulations we can see that condition $(2)$ is logically equivalent to
$$
\underbrace{x_1y_{1}^{2} + x_2y_{2}^{2}}_{\geq 0} +\underbrace{A}_{> 0}\cdot \underbrace{x_1x_2y_{1}^{2}y_{2}^{2}}_{\geq 0} > CD^2 \; \mbox{for all}\quad  x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2\geq 0 \mbox{ and } A>0 \tag{3}
$$
We now have a relation between $C$ and $D$ which is a necessary and sufficient condition for $f(x_k,y_k)>0$.  This condition must be satisfied for any $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2\geq 0$ and for any $A>0$.
And all we've done is algebraic manipulation.  But can we improve it? The answer is yes. And it won't be with algebraic manipulation. It will be with a touch of logic.  One of those logical subtleties that appear in Linear Algebra and Analysis.
Note that $A>0$ is arbitrary and doesn't depend on $x_1$, $x_2$, $y_1$ and $y_2$ and doesn't even depend on $C$ and $D$ either.
Set $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$. Because of the restrictions conditions you'll be fixing $C$ and $D$. Note that we can vary $A>0$ in $(3)$ as much as we like so that the inequality remains valid.  So if we make $A\to 0$ we get $(4)$. So $(3)$ implies $(4)$. On the other hand, $(4)$ implies $(3)$. Take a moment to conclude this.
$$
\underbrace{x_1y_{1}^{2} + x_2y_{2}^{2}}_{\geq 0}  \geq \underbrace{CD^2}_{\geq 0} \quad \mbox{for all}\quad  x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2\geq 0 \mbox{ and } A>0 \tag{4}
$$
